# Submitting login form with scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to submit the following form using scrapy :

```html
<form id='phpal_form' action='http://www.cecif.com/connexion-a-votre-compte.html' method='post' enctype='application/x-www-form-urlencoded' class='phpal_form f1 login-form'>
 <input type="hidden" value="http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cecif.com%2Fmembres-votre-espace.html" name="ref">

 <div class="form-line">
  <div class="block-label">
   <label for="user">Email</label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-element">
   <input name="user" id="email" type="text" value="" maxlength="50" class="text-input">
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="form-line">
  <div class="block-label">
   <label for="mdp">Mot de passe</label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-element">
   <input name="mdp" id="mdp" type="password" value="" maxlength="20" class="text-input">
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="form-button">
  <input id="oklogin" type="image" src="/design/defaut/img/ok-button.png" name="cecif_log" value="OK">
 </div>
</form>
```

This is the scrapy class I'm using using, but to no avail.

```js
def parse(self, response):
        
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formid='phpal_form',
            formdata={
                'user': 'USERNAME',
                'mdp': 'PASSWORD',
                'ref': 'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cecif.com%2Fmembres-votre-espace.html',
                'cecif_log' : 'OK'
                },
            callback=self.after_login
            )

    def after_login(self, response):
        # check login succeed before going on
        
        if "Mon compte CECIF" in response.body:
            self.logger.error("Login failed")
            print 'ERROR'
            return
        else:
            print "SUCCESS"
            #start scrapy crawler
```

The above code does not work and the result of the FormRequest is an empty login page, with form submission error info activated.

Any ideas appreciated! Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to log in with browser and check which data should be sent.

[image]

You are trying to submit incorrect `formdata`